# order mysql data based of column values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a search engine from a mysql datadase which displays information in order based on the value of one of the columns in the row, so if row x has a 'quantity' column
with an integer value of 10 any row y has a 'quantity'value of 20, row x should be echoed first so the greatest value is on top and the least on the bottom (no preference for equal values). or alliteratively find a way that the mysql table automatically orders the data this way. is there some kind of function that I could use. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the ORDER BY clause Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

Comment: ok, that sounds like what I'm looking for thanks, I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

To return rows from a query in a specific order, use the `ORDER BY` clause. To get them returned from highest to lowest values, specify the `DESC` (descending) keyword. For example:

```
SELECT f.quantity
  FROM foo f
 ORDER BY f.quantity DESC
```

You are correct, there is no guarantee as to how the rows will be physically ordered when they are stored. Your ONLY guarantee is the `ORDER BY` clause.